# Chart.js Responsive doughnut chart cutout (Mobile-Tablet-Desktop)

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have my graph working, my problem is that I have a **cutout: 120**, that measurement is global,

I need to add a different cutout number on a tablet, for example:
if it is **mobile**, it is: `cutout: 120`
and on a **tablet**: `cutout: 40`.

This is part of the code that I need to improve so that it works as required:

```js
const options = {
          
  type: chartType,
  data: {
    labels: data.labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: data.colors,
        borderColor: data.colors,
        data: data.values,
        borderWidth: 0,
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true, 
        cutout: 120, 
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    // Maintain the original canvas aspect ratio (width / height) when resizing.
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false, //hover 
        displayColors: false,
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

thank you very much if someone can please help me.

Comment: You can use a percentage as cutout, e.g., `cutout: "20%"`

Comment: Thanks @kikon!!  The percentage works for me! 